# Getting data from WordPress database to use at out of WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I set up WordPress, everything is fine. It is under a sub-directory of main website and it use same database with the custom developed website. The path is like below:

http://www.blabla.com/blog/blabla-category-name/bla-post-title/

I need to list the latest three posts at main website (out of WordPress). I looked WordPress db, but could not see any cat name at table :/ so how can I generate such link to post from out of WordPress?

appreciate helps!!

---

just found this article online. working great!!

http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages

Comment: Try taking a look at these articles: [HOWTO: Display Wordpress posts on other pages or web sites](http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages) [Display Wordpress content from outside of Wordpress](http://www.voodish.co.uk/articles/display-wordpress-content-from-outside-wordpress/)

Comment: This should help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_Wordpress_with_Your_Website

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the RSS feed that Wordpress generates using something like [MagicParser](http://www.magicparser.com/). This would allow you to display the most recent posts on your homepage with relative ease.

The preferred method would be to use one of the methods as described by Dav, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql

```
select te.name from wp_posts as p 
left join wp_term_relationships as r on ( p.ID = r.object_id )
left join wp_term_taxonomy as ta on ( r.term_taxonomy_id = ta.term_taxonomy_id )
left join wp_terms as te on ( ta.term_id = te.term_id )
where p.ID = 529
and ta.taxonomy = 'category'
```

where 529 is the post you want to find the category for.